# How do I link strings from different arrays in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, string, random

I decided to spend the lockdown refreshing my language skills and therefore wrote a learning app, including a section for learning vocabs.
So I copy and pasted a few words, made an array with the language1 vocabs and one with the language2 translations, l1-array strings will be spit out randomly by the program. It's supposed to ask me for the translation, then compare it to the actual one and move the vocabs to different arrays depending on how often I got them right.

So far so easy, but as I have over 400 vocabs, I can't link each l1string to it's l2, so I want the program to do it over the position within the array. 
I have two arrays:

```
    <string-array name="voclist">
          <string name="v1">vocab1</string>
          ...
          <string name="v472">vocab472</string>
    </string-array>
    <string-array name="translist">
          <string name="t1">translation1</string>
          ...
          <string name="t472">translation472</string>
    </string-array>
    Random vocab = new Random();
    for (int i=0; i<voclist.length; i++);
```

And now, in a different TextView, I want the translation to pop up. So something like for v#n import t#n in a way that the program understands it.
How do I do that?

Comment: If I understood correctly you should just be able to use your index `i` from your `voclist` for-loop to access the `translist` value. `String voc = voclist[i];` and `String trans = translist[i];`

Comment: how exactly do I extract the i value? Sorry I'm pretty bad with Java

Comment: Why are they in two separate arrays, instead of one array of objects with the word and its translation? Then they would stay together naturally.

Comment: @DavidConrad If I print them out and they r in the same String, they'll be printed out simultanously. I want them only one of them to be shown. Plus I copy and pasted translation and vocab from a different file so they are in different arrays anyway and I don't want to sort them

Comment: Not in the same String, in the same object. An object that represents a string, and its translation, with two fields.

Comment: @DavidConrad mostly because I copied first the vocabs into one array, then the translations to the other one and sorting all of them to their translation would take too much time

Comment: You don't need to sort anything. Just loop through them and add them all to an instance of a new class to hold them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to do the following. Please note, that I'm using [Lists](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html) in this example. It is easier to remove items from them.

```java
private Random random = new Random();
private int currentIndex;

public void nextVocabQuest() {
    if (voclist.isEmpty()) {
        // Do something if no vocabs are left.
        return;
    }
    this.currentIndex = random.nextInt(voclist.size());
    String vocab = voclist.get(this.currentIndex);
    String trans = translist.get(this.currentIndex);
    // Do your question asking here
}

public void onAnswer() {
   // Check if correct
   if (!correct) return;
   /*
    * This removes the answered vocab and translation from the
    * voclist/translist and adds it to different lists for answered
    * vocabulary
    */
   finishedVoclist.add(voclist.remove(this.currentIndex));
   finishedTranslist.add(translist.remove(this.currentIndex));

   // Trigger next question
   this.nextVocabQuest();
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your attempt of trying to explain that to some greenhorn like me, but I still can't extract the "i"-Value... I tried your way and my Output will only be the translation for the last translation of the list, if anything is working at all (varying the Amount of brackets)

Comment: @KanaMoja I made you a repl.it to try it out and see how it works: https://repl.it/repls/ImpartialFussySolaris (Click on "Run" at the top middle of your screen to run it)

Comment: Thank you very much, the whole thing is running now!

Comment: @KanaMoja nice to hear. Please don't forget to accept the answer so that others know, that this problem has been solved :)